Using Material Design 3 (You) theme with PrimeReact?
now I use PrimeReact in my Next.js project and use theme of stylish of this PrimeReact components, as Lara, MD, MD-compat. But only it themes is preseted in PrimeReact. PrimeReact don`t have theme for MD3, but have for MD2 and MD2-compat. Its not beautiful, and i want to have ability of using MD3 stylization.
How I can do it?
In internet too small count of materials

To clarify, are you asking for help integrating the Material Design 3 theme with PrimeReact? If so, can you share your current attempts and specific issues you're facing? This will help us provide relevant suggestions.

My issue: material design 3 theme not founded in list of PrimeReact themes, but MD and MD compat founded, but itsnt beautiful. I want to use md3 design guidelines stylished components of PrimeReact

LIst of prebuilt themes: https://primereact.org/theming/
